# XAMARIN : programatically created layout lost during page navigation between different activities

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have created a Xamarian Form.

```
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/configureScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/dynamicLinearlayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>
   </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Programatically added a layout to Linearlayout inside the ScrollView.

```
LinearLayout dynamicL;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    //.....
    dynamicL = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.dynamicLinearLayout);
}
var layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
layout.Id = 500;
Button btnRemove = new Button(this);
btnRemove.Text = "-";
btnRemove.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
layout.AddView(btnRemove);

//Add to scroll layout
dynamicL.AddView(layout);
```

As soon as I navigate to another page and come back it looses the layout. how can i save it?

After dynamically adding views to page.[image]

Once I navigate to home page and comes back.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I create one sample about navigation between different activities, and come back, the layout still appear, please take a look the following code.

Activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical">
  <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/configureScroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dynamicLinearlayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
</ScrollView>
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="btn" 
    android:id="@+id/button1"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="navigation" 
    android:id="@+id/button2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.cs:

```
 public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    private Button btn;        
    private LinearLayout dynamicL;
    private Button btn1;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        btn.Click += Btn_Click;
        btn1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2);
        btn1.Click += Btn1_Click;
        dynamicL = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.dynamicLinearlayout);              
    }

    private void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity1));
        StartActivity(intent);
    }

    private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.Text = "btn";
        btn.TextAlignment = Android.Views.TextAlignment.Center;
        layout.AddView(btn);
        dynamicL.AddView(layout);
    }
    
}
```

When click Button to navigate to another activity, come back button in device, layout still appear.

Comment: This means, Button named btn still exists? If yes then how is it different from my code?I particularly cant see any difference.

Comment: Can you also attach before and after picture?